# Cross Object Formula Field Error: Field DNE

Tags: formula, formula-field, cross-object

I have a requirement where I want to update a formula field `Foundation Indicator` on a custom object when a `Foundation Field` checkbox is true on the `Lead` object.

I am trying to put a cross object formula on `Foundation Indicator` field i.e

```
IF(
    Lead.Foundation="True",
    IMAGE("servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015j0000001OfOz", "Green" , 15, 15),
    ""
)
```

But I get the error:

> Field Lead does not exist.

What changes do I have to make in order to complete the formula field?

Comment: Are you writing this formula on your custom object or Lead object?

Comment: Assuming it's a custom field... Have you tried __c at the end?

Comment: @sfdcfox you mean `__r`? Good catch though.

Comment: I am writing this formulae on custom object

Comment: To reference the field on Lead object from your custom object you sdhould have suffix ending with __r as mentioned in other comments. For ex: LeadId__r.Foundation

Comment: @kunal just so you know, formula is singular, formulae is plural.

Comment: @javanoob: I tried to use LeadId_r.Foundation but still get the error LeadId_r does not exist ,also I tried to use Lead_r but get the error again

Comment: There is a patient field on the custom object which is lookup value and when I click on patient ,it shows the lead object. Would I have to use the formulae Patient_r.Foundation_c or Lead_r.Foundation_c

Comment: That means the relation between the custom object and lead is through another object called 'Patient'. If I understand correctly, then you should use something like Patient__r.Lead__r.Foundation__c.

Comment: Actually patient is only a lookup field and not an object on custom object

Comment: @kunalgupta, There is no such thing as object on object. If it is a look up relationship then there is a special field and it has some kind of special properties to reach the other object by specifying __r.

Comment: I mean the patient field is on custom object .I tried using the Patient_r.Lead_r.Foundation_c,still it shows error

Comment: Can you attach screenshot? Are you writing formula by entering field names? or you are using the Insert Fields button on top of the formula editor?

Comment: yes I am using the insert field button on top of the formulae editor

Comment: @kunalgupta , something is not right. If you use the Insert field button, you should not run into this error. Can you attach screenshot or video of what you are doing? You can use software jing techsmith to record a video. Thanks!

Comment: @javanoob : I checked it was the double __ that I was missing instead I was using a single _ which was throwing error.Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @kunalgupta , I am glad you figured it out!